# Select grand parent element attribute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm not so sharp on jquery but am setting up an analytics implementation (Using Google Tag MAnager) that uses titles.

I have this line:

```
var linkTitle = $(this).attr('title');
```

The this in question is a form checkbox and it has no title attribute. The grand parent li, however, does. I'd like to select the grand parent title attribute. Is that possible?

The structure is like so:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this.

```
$(this).parent().attr('title');
```

or you can also do like this.

```
 $(this).parents('li').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
$(this).closest('li').attr('title');
```

`closest()` returns the first element from the ancestors of the `$(this)` jQuery node/object which matches the selector (`li`) passed to the method, and will then access its `title` attribute.

The benefit of using `closest()` (in place of `parent()`) is that `closest()` requires less prior knowledge of the DOM structure, and allows for other ancestors to be inserted between the two (so if the `input` is wrapped in a new `div`, or `fieldset`, it doesn't matter; `closest()` will still work).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: But closest is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: The structure shouldn't be changing, `parent()` appears faster, and `parent()` is also clearer in it's intent than `closest`.

Comment: @Anilkumar `.closest()` isn't deprecated, the particular syntax `.closest(selectors [, context ])` is though: noted [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest2)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the parent element via the [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function.

```
var linkTitle = $(this).parent().attr('title');
```