# Change the divs style in parent of parent using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the `div`'s style which is located in the parent of a parent. I am able to access them via DOM, but how can I change its `CSS` style using `JQuery`?

Selection code:

```
window.parent.parent.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('code').
```

I would love to only change a div that doesn't have `display:none` already set, but I really don't care if we change only one, or all of them.

Comment: Why jQuery when you already have it in JS? Simple look and set display...`var nested = window.parent.parent.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('code'); for(var i=0;i<nested.length;i++){ nested[i].style.display="none"; }`

Comment: you can change style with [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: `window.parent.parent.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('code').style.display = 'block';`

Comment: @AwladLiton Wrong. This function returns a list of elements.

Comment: Remove your comments @AmitJoki, better not to interfere with the wall's question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743846/select-grand-parent-element-attribute, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730035/how-to-change-css-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `context` parameter on `$( selector [, context ] )`

```
$("[name=code]",parent.parent.parent.document).css('display','none');
```

If you want to only change the one that are visible you can use the `is` function in JQuery in order to filter:

```
$("[name=code]",parent.parent.parent.document).is(':visible').css('display','none');
```

JQuery page: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: 1) 
    $("[name=code]",parent.parent.parent.document) This returns 0 occurences. But I've written such line
    $(window.parent.parent.parent.document).find('code') which returns correct number of occurences.

2) .is(':visible') This returns true or false, so you can not apply css to it.

P.S. I've found the solution.